# How get pdf file from httparty get response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, wicked-pdf

I would like render a PDF with wicked_pdf or download it from GET response with httparty,

I succeed to do it with `curl -o filename url` but i dont know how do it with Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```rb
filename = "tmp/test.pdf"
File.open(filename, "w") do |file|
  file.binmode
  HTTParty.get(URL_TO_PDF, stream_body: true) do |fragment|
    file.write(fragment)
  end
end
```

Replace `URL_TO_PDF` with your pdf url